# How to set server snippets Config in Nginx Ingress with Helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress, azure-aks, azure-front-door

Related Github Issue : https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/6519

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  server-snippet: |
    if ($http_x_azure_fdid !~* "55ce4ed1-4b06-4bf1-b40e-4638452104da" ) {
        return 403;
    }
  use-forwarded-headers: "true"
kind: ConfigMap
```

How to achieve the above config using helm when setting the values in the following approach?

```
helm upgrade --install nginx-ingress-controller ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
    --namespace "${namespace}" \
    --version "${chart_version}" \
    --set controller.replicaCount="${replicas}" \
    --set-string controller.config.use-forwarded-headers=true \
    --set-string controller.config.server-snippet=<?> \
    --debug
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a multiline environment variable as below,

```
read -d '' conf << EOF
if ($http_x_azure_fdid !~* "55ce4ed1-4b06-4bf1-b40e-4638452104da" ) {
       return 403;
}
 EOF
```

Once the environment variable is defined, refer it in the helm `--set-string controller.config.server-snippet=` arg as below,

```
helm upgrade --install nginx-ingress-controller ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
    --namespace "${namespace}" \
    --version "${chart_version}" \
    --set controller.replicaCount="${replicas}" \
    --set-string controller.config.use-forwarded-headers=true \
    --set-string controller.config.server-snippet=$conf \
    --debug
```